# Both data.sql file is being used from resources and test resources folder when a @DataJpaTest Junit is being run

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test

Both data.sql file is being used from resources and test resources folder when a annotated @DataJpaTest Junit is being run.

How do I tell spring boot to use only the data.sql in the test resources folder when Junit tests annotated with @DataJpaTest is being executed?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your unit test

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
@Sql(scripts={"classpath:data.sql"})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@shodz... try this.

    @SqlGroup({
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:beforeTestRun.sql"),
        @Sql(executionPhase = Sql.ExecutionPhase.AFTER_TEST_METHOD, scripts = "classpath:afterTestRun.sql")

              })
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this.